# 1992 Toyota pu 4cyl 4wd won't start

Tags: toyota, starting, fuel-system, fuel-injection

I bought this truck basically blind, not knowing anything but the mileage (over 200k) & that it wasn't locked up. The truck has been parked for over a year, it is getting plenty of spark but no gas, I checked the timing, putting it on TDC, timing ok, even tried spraying a little ether while turning it over, not even a cough, I figured at least a back fire. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to ask the previous owner for any history that could point you in the direction of the fault? This needs going back to basics. Check that you actually have petrol in the tank, could be anything in there, check for water or diesel or any other contamination. Don't go by the fuel gauge for tank level, it might be mis-reading. Take out the plugs, any compression? Cam belt or chain turning the cam? Disconnect the fuel pipe at the engine and feed it into a container, pumping **fuel**? Do you have anything blocking the air inlet, a birds nest or dead squirrel? Cover the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Check that muffler internals have not corroded and collapsed there by blocking exhaust;
just tap with a rubber mallet and listen for rattling inside. Inadvertently backing car into a dirt bank can also block exhaust preventing starting.